# saving value from form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms

So, storing a Java String into a form hidden input value. I call said value via javascript and attempt to store it into a var. Strangely, I can display the value via alert but javascript crashes when I try to save it into a var.

The first line is from the initializing jsp file. It does some stuff that gets the string. The string is a list of ints that I plan on splitting in javascript for some stuff.

```
"<form id = \"listArrForm\"> <input id = \"listArr\" value = "+ output +" type = \"hidden\"></form>"

var listArr = document.getElementById("listArr").value; //Does work

alert(document.getElementById("listArr").value); //Does work
```

So yea, I'm guessing it has to do with the the type of value being retrieved?

Comment: 'var listArr ...' does not work even if you 'alert(listArr)' afterward?

Comment: Fix your HTML. Remove the spaces in `id = "listArrForm"` as `id="listArrForm` as well as all other attributes.

Comment: And surround `output` in quotes as `value='" + output + "'`

Comment: So, I'm not sure what happened but it's working now /boggle...maybe I was having connection issues with the apache server and it was screwing with the String variable. Whatever, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, both should work as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2eWja/

What are you storing in the value that makes the script not work? Are you sure you're not putting quotes in?

Answer (score 0):

what browser are you using? There could be problem for [some](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/799232-browser-bug-document-getelementbyid-gets-wrong-element-ie)

Btw using getElementById is known to be wrong. ;)